# Uploading a file will pass a null object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following `_CreateOrEditPartial` partial view which contain a text & a file upload:-

```
@model TMS.Models.DataCenter
@* This partial view defines form fields that will appear when creating and editing entities *@
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div>
    <span class="f">Name </span>    
    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div>
    <span class="f">Data Center Picture </span>    
    <input type="file" name="DataCenterfile" />
</div>
```

and the following main view :-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","DataCenter", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary"/>
}
```

Which will call the following ActionMethod:-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Edit", Model = "DataCenter")]
public ActionResult Create(DataCenter dc, HttpPostedFileBase DataCenterfile)
{
    // Verify that the user selected a file
    if (DataCenterfile != null && DataCenterfile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // extract only the fielname
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(DataCenterfile.FileName);
        // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
        DataCenterfile.SaveAs(path);
    }
```

but the datacenterfile will always be null .. can anyone advice what is causing this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Where is your `form`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the `enctype` attribute to your form.

Something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

}
```

About `enctype` attribute: [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)